# Correct synonym for seethe

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, synonyms

> You simply seethe with unlikely emotions.

The line is taken from a play called " Visit to a small planet". Actually I'm preparing for exams and there is a MCQ which I'm having a problem with.

Which of the following options would be the best synonym for "seethe"?

1. hate
2. avoid
3. show
4. fume

Comment: Welcome to ELL! I'm wondering, though: Did you make up this question? Or find it in a practice exam somewhere? If you found it someplace else, your question would be improved if you told us that. If you went one step further, and explained why you're confused – perhaps even pasting one or two dictionary definitions, showing that you had done some research – this question could even get upvotes. See [Details, Please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) for more tips on how to write an excellent question.

Comment: There are other close synonyms as well: simmer/boil, smolder/burn, teem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To seethe means to be filled with strong emotions, holding them under the surface. Usually, it implies anger.
As such, "avoid" and "show" are not correct, so we're down to either 'hate' or 'fume'.

However, 'seethe' is an intransitive verb; it cannot take a direct object. 'hate' is transitive; it typically takes an object, such as in the sentence:

> I hate **my neighbor's cat**.

To 'fume' is an intransitive verb, and it means either to emit noxious gas, or to be filled with strong emotions— again, usually implying anger.

So, 'fume' is correct.

Answer (score 0):

"***Seethe***" means to be **really angry** and the verb form of "***Fume***" means "**to feel very angry**".

"***Hate***" means to "**dislike intensely**" but it doesn't necessarily mean anger.

Hence, the answer is **4. fume**

Answer (score -1):

The closest in meaning of the four is "show" but actually all of them are quite far from the meaning and even "show" isn't a close synonym. A paraphrase of the entire sentence might be "You are full of surprising and strong emotions"